# Retrofit ignores the timezone

Tags: android, date, timezone, retrofit2

I'm trying to convert the json response into a Date java object, but the timezone on the json response keeps being ignored and the Data object generated keeps using the phone local timezone. Not sure what i'm missing.

This is part of my retrofit initialization:

```
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX")
            .create();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(client)
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();
```

And this is the time returned by the server:

```
"next_date": "2017-03-13T22:30:00-04:00"
```

And this is part of my model:

```
public class DataModel {
    public Date next_date;
}
```

Whenever i check the next_date Date object, the timezone is set to my phone's timezone (i tried setting diff ones), instead of -04:00. Any ideas?

Comment: That's how the `java.util.Date` object works.  It only knows about the machine-local time zone and UTC.  Have you tried using [Joda-Time](https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android)?

Comment: @MattJohnson so whats the point of adding the DateFormat then?

Comment: Since you're de-serializing, that is the expected format of the input.  The `-04:00` is picked up, putting the UTC time four hours ahead.  The `Date` object is created with that value internally.  So you are talking about the same instant in time.  If you want to see that value as a string in another time zone, you'll have to format it with something like `SimpleDateFormatter` and set the time zone explicitly.   However, if you use Joda-Time, you can just use a `DateTime` type, and retain the original time zone.  You'll also need https://github.com/gkopff/gson-jodatime-serialisers